# Permission denied after window.open() in IE7

Tags: javascript, winforms, internet-explorer-7

We have a winforms application with an embedded IE control.

In this IE control, we run a web application (I control the web application but not the winforms application).

In the web application, I run some javascript to open a sub-window and populate it with HTML:

```
    var features = "menubar=no,location=no,resizable,scrollbars,status=no,width=800,height=600,top=10,left=10";
    newTarget = "reportWin" + String ( Math.random () * 1000000000000 ).replace( /\./g ,"" );
    reportWindow = window.open('', newTarget, features); 
    var d = reportWindow.document; // <-- Exception is thrown here
    d.open();
    d.write('<head>\r\n<title>\r\n...\r\n</title>\r\n</head>');
    d.write('<body style="height: 90%;">\r\n<table style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" border="0">\r\n<tr>\r\n<td align="center" valign="middle" style="text-align:center;">\r\n');
    d.write(...);
    d.close();
```

When we run the web application within this WinForms app (but not by itself nor in another WinForms app) we get a Javascript error at the indicated line:

```
Line 0: Access denied
```

Any ideas on why this could be happening or on how I could avoid it?  Note that the window is not opening a URL; it's just an empty window.

From the same application, opening a window with a specified URL in the same domain does work.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a popup-blocker in action?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be pop-up blocker because the window does open.  The problem is trying to access the document object within the winodw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on:

1. [IE 6/7 Access Denied trying to access a popup window.document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735136/ie-6-7-access-denied-trying-to-access-a-popup-window-document)
2. http://thecodecave.com/2006/07/20/how-to-get-around-access-is-denied-in-a-windowopen-javascript-call/

The problem you are having is that the Url being opened needs to be on the same domain as the page that is opening it. Presumably a blank Url will not share the domain of its creator. I wrote a couple of quick test web pages and found

1. Calling `var reportWindow = window.open('', newTarget, features);` resulted in the access denied error.
2. Same thing with `var reportWindow = window.open('http://google.com', newTarget, features);`
3. But opening up another page in the site which does the rendering does work `var reportWindow = window.open('WebForm2.aspx', newTarget, features);`

This last one popped up a window pointing to `WebForm2.aspx` which executed this code:

```
window.document.open();
window.document.write('<head>\r\n<title>\r\n...\r\n</title>\r\n</head>');
window.document.write('test<body style="height: 90%;">\r\n<table style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" border="0">\r\n<tr>\r\n<td align="center" valign="middle" style="text-align:center;">\r\n');
window.document.close();
```