# React render DOM changes in popup, IE error

Tags: internet-explorer, reactjs

I'm trying to render a DOM change with react within a popup. However, if I change the DOM (i.e. adding or removing DOM elements) react throws an error in IE.

Chrome and Firefox works.

I have created a [small example](http://jsfiddle.net/1mu2vqhx/) showing this behaviour.

```
var Page = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.openPopup}>{"Open popup"}</button>
            </div>
        );
    },
    openPopup: function() {
        var popup = window.open('', '', 'width=500,height=500');
        React.render(<Popup />, popup.document.body);
    },
});

var Popup = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var elements = [];
        if(this.state) {
            for(var i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++) {
                elements.push(<div key={i}>{"Line no. "}{i}</div>);
            }
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    onClick={this.countIncrement}
                >{"Add line"}</button><br />
                {elements}
            </div>
        );
    },
    countIncrement: function() {
        var count = 1;
        if(this.state) {
            count = this.state.count + 1;
        }
        this.setState({ count: count });
    }
});

React.render(<Page />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

IE throws an error in [DOMChildrenOperations.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/browser/ui/dom/DOMChildrenOperations.js#L41-L44)

Does anybody know if there is a workaround or some way I can re-render DOM changes in popups with react?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14291880/95190